# R: sum vector's value under condition and resize vector

Tags: r, vector, resize, sum

I have a vector Pn

```
Pn<-c(10,6,7,5,8,1,2,2,3)
```

I need to sum the value till the result is `>= 5` and remove the value that I've summed.  In this case I need the vector to become:

```
Pn= 10,6,7,5,8,1+2+2=5,3
```

the last value (3) is ok because it is impossible to make other. I'm trying with a for loop and a while loop, but I've a problem because the length(Pn) reduce its dimension

```
for (i in 1:(length(Pn)-1)) {
  if (Pn[i]<5) {
    j=i
    while (Pn[j]<5 | j==length(Pn)) {
      Pn[j]<-Pn[j]+Pn[j+1]
      Pn=Pn[-(j+1)]
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a function that solves my question without the loop?

Comment: There are multiple ways to get a sum of 5 with your input vector. Do you choose the first one you come to, or any?

Comment: i don't want a generic sum of 5. i want that all single value must be at less 5. So i scan every single value, if it is < 5 then i sum with the next value till it is at less 5. And then the summed value must be deleted

Comment: In your input vector, if you start at the first entry, `sum(10) >= 5` so shouldn't it end there? What determines that its `1+2+2` that gets summed, instead of any of the other ways you could sum entries of that vector to get something above 5?

Comment: The idea is that i scan the vector from the first index to the last index. 
When i have a value < 5 that index (in this case index number 6) must be summed with the next values till the sum is >= 5 (in this case the index number 7 and 8). so i want to remove the value summed (at the index number 7 and 8) and continue to scan the others index

Comment: I think you can use the loop, but will need to use `c()` instead of just replacing. So something like `c(Pn[1:(i-1)], Pn[j] + Pn[j+1], Pn[(j+2):length(Pn)]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though most R-people hate loops, here is a loop-solution:

```
Pn<-c(10,6,7,5,8,1,2,2,3)

newPn <- vector()
while (length(Pn)>0)
{
  a <- 0
  while (a<5)
  {
    a <- a+Pn[1]
    Pn <- Pn[-1]
    if (length(Pn)==0) {break}
  }
  newPn <- c(newPn,a)
}
```

Result:

```
> newPn
[1] 10  6  7  5  8  5  3
```

A longer example:
Input:

```
 [1]  8  6  5  5  9  3  4  5 10  7  4  6  5  2  3  2  2  5  6  3  7  4 10  2  9  8  8  9 10  6
```

Output:

```
 [1]  8  6  5  5  9  7  5 10  7 10  5  5  9  6 10 14 11  8  8  9 10  6
```